# How to extract multi table from pdf with their page number by using camelot?

Tags: python, python-camelot

I have one pdf file, it has 40 tables in different pages. I want to extract each table with its page number.

I have tried to use this code:

```
import camelot

tables = camelot.read_pdf('2003.pdf', flavor='stream', pages='8,9,10,14,15,18,24...', edge_tol=500, flag_size=True)
for page in range(tables.n):
    tables[page].to_csv(f"2003\Report2003tab{page+1}_page.csv")
```

The output is

```
Report2003tab1_page.csv
Report2003tab2_page.csv
.
.
```

But I want to have output like this:

```
Report2003tab1_page8.csv
Report2003tab2_page9.csv
Report2003tab3_page10.csv
Report2003tab4_page14.csv
```

How can I also include the page numbers in the output?

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned in the [Camelot Quickstart guide](https://camelot-py.readthedocs.io/en/master/user/quickstart.html),

> Now, we have a **TableList** object called `tables`, which is a list of
> **Table** objects. We can get everything we need from this object.
>
> […]
>
> Let's print the parsing report.
>
> ```
> print tables[0].parsing_report
> {
>     'accuracy': 99.02,
>     'whitespace': 12.24,
>     'order': 1,
>     'page': 1
> }
> ```

So you should be able to use:

```
for i in range(tables.n):
    table = tables[i]
    page = table.parsing_report['page']
    table.to_csv(f"2003\Report2003tab{i+1}_page{page}.csv")
```